# how add the user id in another table for additional update information about the user

Tags: cakephp

**Controller/UsersController.php**

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {


    public function beforeFilter() {
         parent::beforeFilter();

      /* allow add action so user can register */
        $this->Auth->allow('add'); 




    }


    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            /* login and redirect to url set in app controller */
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
         /* logout and redirect to url set in app controller */
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

   public function add() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

                //  
        // If the user was saved, Now we add this information to the data
        // and save the Profile.



                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'home'));
                }

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }


    }


}
//





?>
```

here i have add one more table profile (insert Userid in table when user created in **function add()** )
for this i changed more so finally i did found solution so please guide me

Comment: Do you have relations between models like: `User hasOne Profile`?

Comment: Thanks for responding ...no @skywalker

Comment: Have you read this? [HasOne](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to load profile model when saving data in user.

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

  $this->loadModel('Profile'); // it may be different as per your table
  $this->Profile->saveField('field_name', 'value');
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Added Molude name:DrProfile and changed code as `$this->loadModel('Drprofile');
 
  $this->User->Drprofile->saveField('user_id', '$this->User->id');` still shows error in this line

Comment: try like that also $this->Drprofile->saveField('user_id', $this->User->id);

Comment: ya now working but now  `$this->Drprofile->saveField('user_id', $this->User->id);`  getting zero every time;

Comment: if you are getting zero that means you don't have any value in $this->User->Id. I feel you should try to get last insert id as $this->User->getInsertID();